# XDocument check data before try to grab its value

Tags: c#

Please check the c# code bellow. Here i am grabing value of UPC, EAN value from following xml example. But the problem with current code is some time UPC, EAN value is not available in xml and then i get error- Object is not set to an instance... So my question is how can i check the UPC EAN if null before i try to grab its value? So i dont get such missing data error? Any idea to fix?

C# Code:

```
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
        responseStream.Flush();
        responseStream.Close();

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(responseStr);
        XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
        string UPC = "";
        string EAN = "";
        if (doc.Descendants(ns + "Ack").FirstOrDefault().Value != "Failure")
        {
            UPC = doc.Descendants(ns + "UPC").FirstOrDefault().Value;
            EAN = doc.Descendants(ns + "EAN").FirstOrDefault().Value;
        }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<Timestamp>2018-08-04T09:36:11.502Z</Timestamp>
<Ack>Success</Ack>
<Version>1069</Version>
<Build>E1069_CORE_API_18748854_R1</Build>
<Item>
    <ProductListingDetails>
        <ISBN>Does not apply</ISBN>
        <UPC>732030007789</UPC>
        <BrandMPN>
            <Brand>Ommani</Brand>
            <MPN>H0149-OM</MPN>
        </BrandMPN>
        <IncludeeBayProductDetails>true</IncludeeBayProductDetails>
    </ProductListingDetails>
</Item>
</GetItemResponse>
```

Error Pic:
[image: pic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `FirstOrDefault()`, which suggests you know it may be absent - but then you're unconditionally derferencing to use the `Value` property, which will cause a `NullReferenceException` if `FirstOrDefault()` returned null.

Two options:

- Use the null conditional operator:

  ```
  UPC = doc.Descendants(ns + "UPC").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
  ```
- Use the explicit conversion from `XElement` to `string`, which will return null output for null input:

  ```
  UPC = (string) doc.Descendants(ns + "UPC").FirstOrDefault();
  ```

In both cases, `UPC` will end up being null if there's no such element.